# Having issue with sendfile

Tags: node.js, express

I'm attempting to send static html to the client.

I am doing this successfully using this method

```
app.get('/forgot', function (req, res) {
        console.log("Forgot password");

        res.sendFile("Forgot.html", {
            root: "public/statichtml/"
        });
    });
```

However if I use a route like the one below then the client is served the html file however any JS files referenced by the html are looked for in the  'reset' folder - e.g. reset/config.js:

```
 app.get('/reset/:token', function (req, res) {

        User.findOne({
            'local.resetPasswordToken': req.params.token,
            'local.resetPasswordExpires': {
                $gt: Date.now()
            }
        }, function (err, user) {
            if (!user) {

                return res.redirect('/forgot');
            }
            if (user) {

                res.sendFile("Reset.html", {
                    root: "public/statichtml/"
                }, function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        //res.status(err.staus).end()
                    }
                });
            }


        });
    });
```

Can somebody please explain why this might be happening?

Comment: Do you realize that you need routes for all the JS files too?  node.js does not serve anything by default.  Probably you should just put all your static resources (like script files) in one sub-directory and use `express.static()` to serve them all.  If your HTML files are static (not rendered templates), then you can put them in a sub-directory too and use `express.static()` with them too.

Comment: Also, if you use plain filenames with no path for your script filenames in your HTML files, then the browser will add the path of the current web page onto them when requesting them.  Generally, you don't want to use plain filenames with no path on your `<script>` tags unless all your web pages also have no path.  So, put a leading `/` on your script tag filenames.  So `<script src="foo.js"></script>` that is located in a web page with a URL `/reset/index.html` will cause the browser to request `/reset/foo.js`.  Change to something like `<script src="/foo.js"></script>` to fix.

Comment: I should have added that I'm using this code to set the root: app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/statichtml')));

Comment: What's the path on your script tags?  And what's the URL of the pages they are in?

Comment: @jfriend00 - this is howI have setup my src in my html /configuration.js

Comment: Is it actually `<script src="/configuration.js"></script>` in the HTML file?  And, where is `configuration.js` on your server's hard drive?

Comment: HTML is in public/statichtml - js in public/statichtml/reset AND js links to reset/configuration.js in html

Comment: strange thing is it works with route: app.get('/forgot', function (req, res) {} but not with: app.get('/reset/:token', function (req, res) {}

Comment: That sounds like the script tag needs to be `<script src="/reset/configuration.js"></script>`.  Yeah, that's because you have a relative path on the script tag and `/reset/xxx` has a path so that path gets combined with the relative path on your script tag.  Relative paths on script tags are generally troublesome.

Comment: But why does it work with one route type and not another?

Comment: Because one has a URL that isn't top level so the browser tries to combine that path with your relative script filename.  `/reset/xxx` is not top level so the browser will add `/reset/` onto the front of any relative paths it finds in tags.  Get rid of your relative `<script>` paths - problem gone.

Comment: But the only difference is that one route has :token - otherwise they're identical no? Just trying to understand why it works in one route and not another

Comment: Please reread all my comments about what happens when you use a relative script path and you have a path on the URL for the web page.  I've explained it multiple times - one page URL has a path, the other does not.  The one without a page works, the one with a path does not.  `/reset/xxx` has a path of `/reset` which is combined with relative URLs in the page.  If you don't understand something I've written please ask a more specific question as I feel like I've already explained the difference a couple times.

Comment: Now that I'm back on a real computer, I summarized my comments into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you have a relative path issue with the `<script>` tags in your web pages.  Here's what happens.

If you have a web page that is `/index.html` and a `<script>` tag like this:

```
<script src="reset/configuration.js"></script>
```

Then, the browser will see that the path on the containing HTML page is `/` so it will combine that with your script filename and it will request `/reset/configuration.js`.  In your circumstance, it looks like this works fine.

Now, if you have a web page of `/reset/1234` and the same script tag in that page, the browser will see that the page has a path of `/reset` and it will combine that with your script filename and the browser will request `/reset/reset/configuration.js`. which will not work for you.

The way to solve this is to not use relative paths for your script tag.  Instead, add a root level path designation such as this:

```
<script src="/reset/configuration.js"></script>
```

Since this script tag src starts with a `/`, the path from the page will not be used at all and the browser will consistently request `/reset/configuration.js` no matter what the path of the page is.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time..I'll attempt this and report back